# Tokenize with Chef

Tags: chef-infra, tokenize

I'm looking to tokenize lines in a file that will be handled by Chef later.

For example two different files would become one, and we need a token to handle differences:

```
set ns hostName HOST05
set ns hostName HOST06
```

The differences are 05 and 06. They will be in one file, so one line with token.

Looking for a way to tokenize them and have Chef manage the tokens.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correctly you wish to use a [`template`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html) resource like this:

file.erb (The templated file in `mycookbook/templates/default`)

```
<% @tokens.each do |t| %>
set ns hostName HOST<%= t %>
<% end %>
```

In your recipe (in `mycookbook/recipes/default.rb` for example):

```
template "/path/to/target-file" do
  source "file.erb"
  variables("tokens" => ["05","06"])
end
```

This would output a file like your example.